# Query Interceptor in Entity Framework without using WCF data services

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4.1 Code First approach. I do NOT wish to use WCF Data services. Can I still implement Query interceptor? Any pointers regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need them? Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The reason I need is to implement some role based business logic. For instance if there were 2 roles: Admin and Non Admin, and if Admin calls getClients it should return all the clients. If a non admin calls getClients it should return only clients in a particular region. Is it doable? Am I in the right direction looking for Query Interceptors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No EF doesn't offer query interceptors at all. It is purely WCF Data Services addition. You must implement your own infrastructure for such logic but I have some doubts that it is doable on global level.

You can do something like this in your context:

```
public IQueryable<Client> ClientsQuery(IPrincipal principal)
{
    if (prinicipal.IsInRole("Admin") 
    {
        return this.Clients;
    } 
    else
    {
        return this.Clients.Where(...);
    }
}
```

Well, it is not very nice because it moves business logic to data access layer and it is hardcoded. The bigger problem is that it works only if you use `ClientsQuery` in your upper layer instead of `Clients` directly. Even worse is that it works only for direct queries but not for relations. So if you have for example `Product` entity containing navigation property to all clients who ever bought the product this navigation property will never be filtered by your condition because EF doesn't support filtering of navigation properties at all.

There is no general solution for this problem. You business logic must handle this by adding correct conditions where it is needed and using projections in case of filtering navigation properties like:

```
var query = from p in context.Products
            where ...
            select new 
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Clients = p.Clients.Where(...)
                };
```

Btw. navigation properties are not solved by WCF Data Services as well.